# Can somebody show me a simple way to compare strings

Tags: java

I didn't know how to explain the question but hopefully this will make you understand

I know this code does not work

```
a = "hello";
    if (a.equals("hello" || "greetings")){
        //Execute code
    }
```

Is there a simple way to do this without an error

I could do this but this means that i will need to repeat codes on both

```
a = "hello";

    if (a.equals("hello")){
        //Do code
    }
    if (a.equals("greetings")){
        //Execute code
    }
```

This is my current code but its not what i want it to do. 
What i want it to do is if for example `topic = "Whats the date";` i want it to execute the code because it contains date, I cant find a way to check if it contains date and so the || works

```
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String topic = scanner.nextLine();
        topic = topic.toLowerCase();

    if (topic.equals("time") || topic.equals("date")){
        System.out.println("The time is " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
```

Comment: There are plenty of examples, check the link.
[see the .equals() ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: @GurfX You should really read some more of Java programming. The code you posted contain several syntax errors.

Comment: @MCEmperor I know i only used that code so you could understand my question. I knew the code didn't work

Comment: Java has a contains method, no?

Comment: Yes it does, In fact i just retried the code that didn't work last time and it somehow worked, I will answer my question with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You code won't compile since the syntax is not correct in any case.

The answer is **no**, `||` operator works on `boolean` expressions and a `String` is not a `boolean` value.

The meaningful way to do it is the traditional way:

```
if (a.equals("hello") || a.equals("greetings") {
  ..
}
```

If you have many different alternatives for many different tokens then you should consider using a different approach, like a `Map<String, Consumer<String>>` so that you can do something like:

```
Map<String, Consumer<String>> mapping = new HashMap<>();
Consumer<String> greetings = s -> code;

mapping.put("hello", greetings);
mapping.put("greetings", greetings);

...

Consumer<String> mapped = mapping.get(a);

if (mapped != null)
  mapped.accept(a);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (yourString.equals("hello") || yourString.equals("greetings")){
    //Execute code
}
```

If you want to compare your string with ignoring case. Use `equalsIgnoreCase()` method instead of `equals()`

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are correct and on point, but I'd like to change one thing just a bit:

```
if ("hello".equals(a) || "greetings".equals(a)) {
    //...
}
```

That way, you are not risking `NullPointerException` (which would get thrown if `a` is `null`, because you can't execute a method on a `null` object). If you want to ignore the case, use `equalsIgnoreCase(String)`.

Or, alternatively, use `switch`:

```
switch(a) {
    case "hello": //do something
            break;
    case "greetings": //do something
            break;
    default: //handle case where there is no match, if needed
}
```

Comment: using switch will still make me repeat the code, i'm looking to combine them together

Comment: Yeah, in your case it will. Also, depending on the context, you may find `"string literal".equals(string_var)` useful, though with the `Scanner` and/or `System.in` it makes no difference

Answer (score -1):

I found an answer to my question after some experimenting, Sorry about the confusion

```
        scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String topic = scanner.nextLine();
        topic = topic.toLowerCase();

        if (topic.contains("time") || topic.contains("date")){
        System.out.println("The time is " + Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    }
```